# Javascript add value if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```
<p>
    <label for="hours">Learn JavaScript the Hardy Way’ - Complete e-book (Printed)</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="chap7" name="hours" value="0">
</p>

<input type="checkbox" id="printed"/>Please tick if you would like a printed version<br />

<p class="post">Postage : <strong>£<output id="post">0</output></strong><p>
```

I would like a piece of javascript so that upon the checkbox being checked, it makes the postage value 3.50. However, it is 3.50 per copy of the complete ebook. So it would have to check the value of number box and times it by the value inside.

Comment: @Malik im not great with javascript, so only

 if(document.getElementById('printed').checked){
  document.getElementById('post').value + 3.50
 }

Comment: `var total = parseInt(document.querySelector('#chap7').value, 10) * 3.5;`

Comment: "I would like a piece of javascript" -- StackOverflow is not a coding service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Solution that changes based on checkbox state:

```js
var chap7 = document.getElementById('chap7'),
    post = document.getElementById('post'),
    printed = document.getElementById('printed');

printed.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var quantity = parseInt(chap7.value, 10);
  
  post.value = printed.checked ? quantity * 3.5 : quantity;
}, false);

chap7.addEventListener('change', function() {
  post.value = parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
```

```html
<p>
    <label for="hours">Learn JavaScript the Hardy Way’ - Complete e-book (Printed)</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="chap7" name="hours" value="0">
</p>

<input type="checkbox" id="printed"/>Please tick if you would like a printed version<br />

<p class="post">Postage : <strong>£<output id="post">0</output></strong><p>
```

---

#### Solution that changes based on text input state:

```js
var chap7 = document.getElementById('chap7'),
    post = document.getElementById('post');

chap7.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var quantity = parseInt(chap7.value, 10);
  
  post.value = quantity * 3.5;
}, false);
```

```html
<p>
    <label for="hours">Learn JavaScript the Hardy Way’ - Complete e-book (Printed)</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="chap7" name="hours" value="0">
</p>
<p class="post">Postage : <strong>£<output id="post">0</output></strong><p>
```

Comment: Brilliant this works, how would i go about re-using this for another part, with no checkbox involved?

Comment: Sorry i thought i had made it clear, literally exactly how it works but with no listener for the check box. So the value of the numberbox * 3.50 essentially.

Comment: @CameronHowson, I've added another solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been incredibly helpful